# How to turn a 'string list' into a real list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am opening a `.txt` file and have to use a list inside of it for a function I am writing. This is one of the lists given in the text file:

```
'[24, 72, 95, 100, 59, 80, 87]\n'
```

Using `.strip()` it gets rid of the `\n`, so it becomes:

```
'[24, 72, 95, 100, 59, 80, 87]'
```

I think using split would be useless, because using `split(' ')` would yield:

```
['[24, 72, 95, 100, 59, 80, 87]']
```

Which I think just deepens the complications. What is an effective way to turn this 'string list' into a real list I could use a for loop with? I've been trying for a few hours already, and can't figure it out.

Comment: eval can e used in this case

Comment: ANother way could be json.load and dump. You create the file using json.dump and read it using it json.load

Comment: `.split(' ')` should have produced `['[24,','72,','95,','100,','59,','80,','87]']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
In [8]: strs='[24, 72, 95, 100, 59, 80, 87]\n'

In [9]: from ast import literal_eval

In [10]: literal_eval(strs)
Out[10]: [24, 72, 95, 100, 59, 80, 87]
```

help on `ast.literal_eval`:

```
In [11]: literal_eval?
Type:       function
String Form:<function literal_eval at 0xb6eaf6bc>
File:       /usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py
Definition: literal_eval(node_or_string)
Docstring:
Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
expression.  The string or node provided may only consist of the following
Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans,
and None.
```

Comment: When I use the default Idle shell, it works fine, but when I woke outside of it, say in the folder I am working on, it returns error "no module named ast"

Comment: @HaileyMonette python version?

Comment: Actually you are correct, for some reason Idle 2.5 ran instead of 2.7.3, but this solution does work, thanks a lot!

Comment: @HaileyMonette This was introduced in py2.6.

Answer (score 3):

An answer has already been accepted, but I just wanted to add this for the record. The json module is really good for this kind of thing:

```
import json
s = '[24, 72, 95, 100, 59, 80, 87]\n'
lst = json.loads(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
strs='[24, 72, 95, 100, 59, 80, 87]\n'
list_of_strs = ast.literal_eval(strs)
```

Further help, leave a comment....

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to go importing anything for this

> s = '[24, 72, 95, 100, 59, 80, 87]'
>
> s.translate(None, '[]').split(', ') will give you a list of numbers that are strings

if you want a list of ints try

> [int(i) for i in s.translate(None, '[]').split(', ')]