# Python - read lists in a csv

Tags: python, list, csv, pandas

I have a problem, I can not read a CSV file containing a columns made by list of float.
This is the method I used to save the CSV. data is a list of tuples.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=['ColA', 'ColB'])
df.to_csv(FILE, index=False, header=True)
```

In this way i get the following file in output, which is fine.

```
ColA,ColB
"[1.5,2.5,3.5]",9
"[4.5,5.5,6.5]",9
"[3.5,1.5,8.5]",9
```

Now, when I try to load the file in this way

```
df = pandas.read_csv(FILE)
mylist = []
for x in xrange(len(df['ColA'])):
    mylist.append(df['ColA'][x])
```

I get list of strings instead a list of lists. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I do not think the comma is a problem. Look at this code.

```
import pandas
FILE = 'file.csv'

listA = [[1.1, 1.2, 1.3], [2.1, 2.2, 2.3], [3.1, 3.2, 3.3]]
listB = [9.1, 9.2, 9.3]

data = map(lambda x, y: (x, y), listA, listB)
df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=['ColA', 'ColB'])
df.to_csv(FILE, index=False, header=True)

df = pandas.read_csv(FILE)
print df['ColA'][0], df['ColA'][0][0]
```

The output is `[1.1, 1.2, 1.3] [` instead of `1.1`

Comment: You saved a string "[1.5,2.5,3.5]". So you get a string back :). You can use eval(""[1.5,2.5,3.5]""), but I hear it's bad practice.

Comment: I guessed that was the error, but what I am passing is a list not a string. Should I specify the type in some way?

Comment: I'm not sure if csv has a list concept that maps to a list in python. You could write the list as a **string** (real string, not in the form of `str(list)`) using `",".join(your_list)` and get it back using `retrieved_string.split(',')`, but you may never include anything containing commas in that list, since it'll ruin the mapping. If that's OK - that's a good solution. Have you considered using our lord and saviour JSON?

Comment: Yes, that can be a solution since it is a list of float numbers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need to know is how to go from strings to lists and strings to numerals please refer to this post [How to turn a 'string list' into a real list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255477/how-to-turn-a-string-list-into-a-real-list) and the Python docs at https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float

Comment: I replied to you in the first post. However, the topic you linked can be useful.

Comment: I see, it is clear now. You need to look at the Question I linked to indeed.
The reason you get `[` instead of `1.1` is that `[` is the first character in the string. It is basically what you ask for by doing `df['ColA'][0][0]`

Comment: I did, in fact I solved by doing ast.literal_eval(df['ColA'][x] in a loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if CSV has a concept of complex objects such as lists. You can map your lists to strings by using `",".join(your_list)` given that you only use floats.

Mapping back the stored string that represents a list would be as simple as `retrieved_string.split(',')`.

You may want to consider a format that supports lists such as JSON, which is also more friendly (from my experience) when using python.